# TypeScript: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foo | Bar'

Tags: typescript

I have a code like:

```
// Those two come from backend, it cannot be guaranted
// they do not contain additional fields of any type.
interface Foo1 {
    name: string;
}

interface Foo2 {
    description: string;
}

// This one is mine and should always contain valid types
class Bar {
    text: string;

    constructor(data: Foo1 | Foo2 | Bar) {
        this.text = data.name || data.description || data.text;
        // Some more similar rules and throwing exceptions
        // if types are incorrect
    }
}
```

The problem is TypeScript cries that the `name` does not exist on `Bar` and `text` does not exist on `Foo` etc., despite the fact that no matter the type of the `data` one of them will surely exist making `this.text` always set to the correct type.

How to specify typescript types here to avoid such problems but still accept both types in constructor?

ps. I'm not asking about `instanceof`, it does not work with interfaces. I'm asking about annotating types correctly and only about that. Altering the logic of the code is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Use a type guard (ie an `instanceof` check in this case) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNwEC+BBCANnDTcgBCcKDgLFkkAB5hqdBiBadCxBOhDyArgjDooACgAmcMHGoYsAHyEiAlGJUSiYABbAaAOmlhkAXmTGpsigdHAgSOgwNqIA-AEmcF4QMsjU8aYepBSsjsgc+GxAA

Comment: Thanks for trolling the fact I simplified my code to not waste y'all time! I've added more details to the question. Also `instanceof` does not work on interfaces.

Comment: I did not downvote, but please keep things civilized, as stated the answer was 'read the docs' simple. My guess is that this is why it was down-voted ..

Comment: `(data as Foo1).name || (data as Foo2).description` is one option, but this highlights that taking lots of different types probably suggests an issue elsewhere, maybe you need a facade or adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to narrow a union is always a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). You can never access uncommon properties of a union.

Using type guards you could rewrite the code as:

```
class Bar {
    text: string;

    constructor(data: Foo1 | Foo2 | Bar) {
        this.text = 'description' in data ? data.description:
            'name' in data ? data.name :
            data.text;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsHsGcFNQBcDu1QGNoFtEDMAnHUAIwEMMBreAOwBMAaUASyUzJpujZMQHMArmQIck8OgFgAUCGSR4AT1B10XNlhpIyzGqDJ06rZtBpkANqDzN4ZurFDQ8emkqQKADvAB00nWIJ4FIgAYtDQAIygAN7SoHGgprgAXKCwSAQ6fADc0gC+0r6a8AFBoKHQAEzRsfF08LAYGe5IxjQpaRk02XkFMmBQzPYmiIOg2DqIHHSpMAK2emYoZAr2Glo6oABu5szTbp6w0hhmZLD2AELC1VLxyPAAHkjt6Zk5UjVxGh0CGEjQBAAKOhkLQpcqRAA+ZTCVShlwIAEprrdbkhIIMvGJHqAALygADkdQaTRaJnxLF0wK0oAA-MoQWQvETGsxmq0kh8Ubd8Yl4OSNlSyLT6VovLzQByblyUYLMQ8kG9bvkpLkgA)

You can create a custom type that forces all union  constituent to have all properties, but defined as `undefined`. This will allow access to common properties:

```
interface Foo1 {
    name: string;
}

interface Foo2 {
    description: string;
}

type KeyOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type ExpandUnionHelper<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends T ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, undefined>> : never
type ExpandUnion<T> = ExpandUnionHelper<T, KeyOfUnion<T>>
// This one is mine and should always contain valid types
class Bar {
    text: string | undefined; 

    constructor(data: ExpandUnion<Foo1 | Foo2 | Bar>) {
        this.text = data.text || data.name || data.description
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsHsGcFNQBcDu1QGNoFtEDMAnHUAIwEMMBreAOwBMAaUASyUzJpujZMQHMArmQIck8OgFgAUCGSR4AT1B10XNlhpIyzGqDJ06rZtBpkANqDzN4ZurFDQ8emkqQKADvAB00nWIJ4FIgAYtDQAIygAN7SoHGgprgAXKCwSAQ6fADc0gC+0r6a8AFBoKHQAEzRsfF08LAYGe5IxjQpaRk02XkFUm6eoADSigDyeACqNK0APOAAfKAAvBCg8AAeYvT24KAA-KDUCo4rKTTwAG7FOX0eiACia+4cdJOtABI2ngSzTIOrG7Q7KAAApEL5uYYKBbLHbrTZAnb7HYAMhBwha5mmACV4FgCHRpg8MGYBHVpoMmIdjvMmAJ6PArGc6HMFqcLsVpP17o9nq8TLNoaAHk96HyaB8zF8fkNRhMpvz5nNpLIoMx7CZEGrQNgdIhnqkYAJbHozCgyAp7BotDpQOdzMw6MhbrBpMSyLB7AAhYTVKTxZBw9rpTKgAA+oDpdUZ4iyoF6-o0HQEGCQ0AIAAo6GQtClhbz5TRpuVIuHylVw96CHMAJS+-3+pCQNVeMQbJbKbNkFtwsPhrNaLyJRChvudrx1BpNFomGpxfJSXJAA)

But this will not be an exact result as it is typed as `string | undefined`

The simplest solution may be to use a type assertions, while not very elegant, it should be ok in this case.

```
// This one is mine and should always contain valid types
class Bar {
    text: string;

    constructor(data: Foo1 | Foo2 | Bar) {
        this.text = (data as Foo1).name || (data as Foo2).description || (data as Bar).text;
        // Some more similar rules and throwing exceptions
        // if types are incorrect
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=18&pln=10&pc=12#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0EZkG8CwAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcRAvkUaJLIigzoATHiKlkAEwh0ETAA5hg6ELQZMQbTt0IB6XcgAqAC2B1kKlGeQVQKOCEn1j6AK4AbJ3HcB3OAE9zBBUwOFBkADdvYCcwf3kZIgR3ODpzACE4KDFiUkgADzA1RhZ2QnFSYJB1VwQwdCgACkk4UNohHAAfNExRbsyoAEociQkwUzoAOgKwZABeZGbWuGRUnuxByfIqZE7updDV8yFhTelZBSUVXf2Ww7WBzZmy0dJ9ZABldB2KBpQ6YC2FLZKAeGSrRzIcZQdA+FjICD5JCKZTVCqvd7AGBQ+LgrJWEDBKBQCB1dHILiEDhAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.text = 
'name' in data ? data.name 
: 'description' in data ? data.description 
:  data.text;
```

The issue is that TS not allows to check properties in values representing types without these properties. Every time you want to access such, there needs to be check of existing this property or type assertion by `as`

There is some more info why is that - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12815